# Python function does not return expected result

Tags: python, list, function, return

I am having some trouble with my functions. Instead of the desired list being
returned, I am getting what looks like a memory address. It would be very good
if someone could point out where I am going wrong.

Here is the code

```
def listing():
    t = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    return t

m = listing
print m
```

and here is what I get on the command line.

```
<function listing at 0x7f6d5f9f5a28>
```

Comment: You need to use `()` to call a function: `m = listing()`

Comment: Why would *anyone* downvote this? Why would SO punish someone who is trying to learn and demonstrates his steps accordingly?

Comment: @TheInternet, you're right. This is a gotcha for beginners and doesn't deserve a downvote. BUT. one of the stages of becoming a developer includes the belief that all beginners are stupid. Downvoters will eventually grow up ;-)

Comment: don't why it isnt show all of the question

Comment: thanks for the help guys. I'm not bothered by the downgrade. Like you say, someone else my have this problem.

Comment: @TheInternet: The initial post didn't use indentation and the return value wasn't visible (anything in angle brackets is filtered out unless on the HTML tag whitelist). Only after I edited the post was that piece of evidence.. evident.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Thank you for editing the post, but incorrect formatting doesn't deserve a downvote IMO. If it's someones first time on the website, they have no idea what they are doing obviously, how can they be expected to know markup syntax or python whitespace rules if they don't know function invocation, the 11 rep told you that.

Comment: @DavidRobinson, keep programming son, don't let the parasitic SO community eat you alive!

Comment: @TheInternet: I didn't downvote this post; the formatting *hid* the information, and the Python code was also incorrectly formatted. I *did* vote to close this question; not calling function is a simple typographical error, in my opinion.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, it's not typographical because it's still valid python. It deals with programming. I'm glad you didn't downvote, but closing, why would we turn him away?

Comment: @TheInternet it's an extremely simple error, the likes of which are encountred by many beginner developers every day. A variant of this exact problem is asked at least twice a week here. Closing the question has nothing to do with "turning him away" (he _did_ get a solution) but with keeping the quality standards of SO, which is explicitly not meant for hosting countless variations of these kinds of beginner mistakes (it could be closed as a dupe instead but "typo" is just as valid). Regarding the downvoting, the question is poorly researched and thus deserves it; unlike the 2 upvotes it got.

Answer (score 5):

You forgot to **call** the function:

```
m = listing()
```

Without the `()` all you did is store another reference to the function object.

Answer (score 2):

use function call

```
m = listing()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably used to a language that doesn't require parentheses for calling a function. Perl and Visual Basic come to mind. Check this out:

```
>>> def listing():
...     t = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
...     return t
...
>>> m = listing
>>> print m
<function listing at 0x100491b90>
>>> m()
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>>
```

So, your line `m = listing` just assigned the function (what `listing` refers to) to another name (`m`). Objects can have as many names as you like. And functions are also objects. Objects that can be called using the operator `()`.

BTW:

```
>>> listing
<function listing at 0x100491b90>
```

kind of proves the point...